# Percentage Calculation of a total amount

Tags: percentages

Maths was never my strong point however I have a total of `$350` how can I calculate it so that I can get `25%` of the total `$350`?

Comment: You multiply 350 by .25. In general, $x$% of $y$ is just $\frac{x}{100}\cdot y$.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a value $V $ and you want $x $% percent of it, just multiply $V$ by $\frac {x}{100} $ to get

$$V \times \frac {x}{100} $$

In our case we get

$$350 \times \frac {25}{100} = 87.5 $$